# In python, how do i read a page which takes some time to load?

Tags: python

following python code doesnt let the page to load completely:

```
    import urllib
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    url = "https://qualcomm.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/External"
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    # kill all script and style elements
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
        script.extract()    # rip it out

    # get text
    text = soup.get_text()
    
    # break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
    lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
    # break multi-headlines into a line each
    chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
    # drop blank lines
    text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

    print(text)
```

Comment: That's not a matter of the page taking time to load. `urllib` can't run Javascript. If you're expecting to run Javascript, you're going to need browser automation, not `urllib`.

Comment: You can use `time.sleep()` to pause the program while the page is loading.

Answer (score 0):

When you analyse the website correctly, it's loading the data via an ajax call. The following script saves the json data to a file where all the data is there

```
import requests, json


headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json,application/xml",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Host": "qualcomm.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "Referer": "https://qualcomm.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/External",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
}


res = requests.get("https://qualcomm.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/External?clientRequestID=389507c8b0584f96b156c21475f69adf", headers=headers, verify=False)

data = res.json()

with open("data.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```